# how can I give directions to the woman's restroom and man restrooms?

Tags: idioms, american-english, idiomatic-language, idiom-request, idioms-in-context

I work in a casino and sometimes guests ask me for directions. I usually say "it's outside the casino, on the lobby. go straight and it's on your left (for woman's) but I realize that they get confused . if I'm x point.
[image]

Comment: Note that we normally pluralize the initial adjectival element in [***men's / women's restroom/s***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=women%27s+restroom%2Cwoman%27s+restroom&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#), regardless of whether the "head" noun *(**restroom/s**)* is singular or plural.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of the layout even with your diagram, but I'd suggest:

> Go straight out of the casino towards the lobby. The women's will be on your left and the men's on your right.

Comment: I have to say this is incorrect. "Outside" means outside of a building, in the open air. It seems to me that the restrooms are inside the building, just not the main casino area.

Comment: @Astralbee Fair enough; reworded.

Answer (score 3):

The 'lobby' of a building is normally *inside*. It has walls and a roof, right? So you would say '**in**' the lobby, not 'on' it.

Secondly, a building's lobby is normally considered to be part of the same building that it serves. The entire building would probably be considered to be 'the casino', not just the area in which gambling takes place. So the restrooms may be described as 'out' of the main area, but they are not 'outside' of the casino, as that normally means something exterior to the building.

Depending on what is most idiomatic in your particular dialect of English, you could perhaps describe the location of the restrooms this way:

- The restrooms are off the lobby
- The restrooms are out in the lobby
- The restrooms are back out in the lobby (*esp. if they have come through the lobby in order to get to the main area*)
- The restrooms are on either side of the lobby

Or if you wanted to give directions:

- Go out to the lobby, the women's restroom is on the left, men's on the right
- Head to the lobby, turn left for the women's restroom, turn right for the men's.

If the lobby is an area that visitors have to pass through in order to enter the main casino area, then they must surely know where it is without being told they need to leave the main casino area.